# Sed substitution places characters after back reference at beginning of line

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file that I am trying to convert to a Latex file for printing. One of the first steps is to go through and change lines that look like:

```
Book 01        Introduction
```

To look like:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
```

To this end, I have devised a very simple sed script:

```
sed -n -e 's/Book [[:digit:]]\{2\}\s*(.*)/\\chapter{\1}/p'
```

This does the job, except, the closing curly bracket is placed where the initial backslash should be in the substituted output. Like so:

```
}chapter{Introduction
```

Any ideas as to why this is the case?

Answer (score 3):

Your call to `sed` is fine; the problem is that your file uses DOS line endings (CRLF), but `sed` does not recognize the CR as part of the line ending, but as just another character on the line. The string `Introduction\r` is captured, and the result `\chapter{Introduction\r}` is printed by printing everything up to the carriage return (the `^` represents the cursor position)

```
\chapter{Introduction
                     ^
```

then moving the cursor to the beginning of the line

```
\chapter{Introduction
^
```

*then* printing the rest of the result (`}`) over what has already been printed

```
}chapter{Introduction
 ^
```

The solution is to either fix the file to use standard POSIX line endings (linefeed only), or to modify your regular expression to not capture the carriage return at the end of the line.

```
sed -n -e 's/Book [[:digit:]]\{2\}\s*(.*)\r?$/\\chapter{\1}/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `sed`, `awk` using `gsub` might work well in this situation:

```
awk '{gsub(/Book [0-9]+/,"\\chapter"); print $1"{"$2"}"}'
```

**Result**:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to modify the capture group. In this case, since all book chapter names consist only of alphabetic characters I was able to use `[[:alpha:]]*`. This gave a revised sed script of:

```
sed -n -e 's/Book [[:digit:]]\{2\}\s*\([[:alpha:]]*\)/\\chapter{\1}/p'.
```